# Why do pages look good when logged in to Admin but not when logged out

Tags: themes, pages

I recently decided to start using DIVI to begin rebuilding my site one page at a time. When I am logged in the pages (home and about) look great. When I am logged out they are terrible, some info not updated and images are missing.... I have no idea what to do.

[www.vealliance.com](http://www.vealliance.com)

Comment: Are you using a cache plugin? Are you clearing the cache before you log out so the cached pages get rebuilt? Have you checked with Divi support about any of this?

Comment: I would also suspect it's a caching issue. I'm not seeing any missing images on your home page. Check from another device that hasn't visited the site before if you have access to one.